# using transaction without try catch

Tags: stored-procedures

I want to use transaction without try catch. But I don't know to allocate rollback. This following statement is alway commit. Please help me. @@Error can catch one error. So, I want not to use this.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

     INSERT Person values (@name,@age);
     INSERT User values (@name,@age);

IF @@TRANCOUNT>0
     COMMIT TRANSACTION
ELSE
     ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Comment: Are you still confused about this @zahntet, or did you finally figure out why the fact that @@trancount is always above zero?

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you `BEGIN TRANSACTION` then `@@TRANCOUNT` is incremented.

So because you did increment it once, then it will *always* be `>0`

You probably mean to check `IF ( @@ERROR > 0 ) ROLLBACK TRAN`

Also, I would encourage you to use named transactions so you know you're rolling back the right transaction (if for no other reason than traceability)

Answer (score 0):

@@Error only catches the last statement error code, but if you check after every insert statement - I think you'd achieve desired behavior.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

 INSERT Person values (@name,@age);

IF (@@ERROR <> 0) BEGIN
    PRINT 'Unexpected error occurred!'
    ROLLBACK TRAN
    RETURN 1
END

 INSERT User values (@name,@age);

IF (@@ERROR <> 0) BEGIN
    PRINT 'Unexpected error occurred!'
    ROLLBACK TRAN
    RETURN 1
END

 COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: If you have many transactions - you can use GOTO to reduce the amount of code you need to copy/paste

Answer (score -1):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

     INSERT Person values (@name,@age);
     INSERT User values (@name,@age);

IF @@ERROR == 0
     COMMIT TRANSACTION
ELSE
     ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```